# Make executable from gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, executable

I have a gradle project that inspects java code and makes class diagrams out of it. I have a one line shell script that runs gradle with commandline arguments for the location of the source files and the output name of the image.

If someone downloaded my project, they could run the shell script by typing `./myprogram.sh arg1 arg2` on the commandline.

I want someone to be able to download my project and run it on the commandline by typing `myprogram arg1 arg2`.

How can this be done with a gradle project?

Comment: Can't you build a executable jar ? so  to execute your program, someone can just type  `java -jar myprogram .jar "arg 1" arg2@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Gradle's [Distribution Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html). It allows you to create a distribution of your program, which is a ZIP file containing your JAR files and init scripts, that, when added to the system `PATH`, would allow you to run your program like you want. The Gradle documentation is quite thorough. The gist is to make sure you have this in your `plugins` block:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}
```

Assuming your main class is configured properly with Gradle:

```
application {
    mainClassName = 'your.main.Class'
}
```

You can just run `gradle distZip` to generate the distribution (it'll be in the `distributions/` folder of your build directory). Then, your users can extract it to a location of their choice and add the `bin/` directory to their system `PATH`. To customize the name of the command:

```
startScripts {
    applicationName = 'myprogram'
}
```